# Jlayer in a Jpanel with circular loading bar

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayer

here is my exemple of making a circular loading bar with Jlayer but now the layer start and stop after the execution of the btnLoad.addActionListener() and stop after a while of determinated timer (4000) so my problem that I need it to start when I click the button load 
and stop after complete the loading of the file !!!

```
  final WaitLayerUI layerUI = new WaitLayerUI();

       jlayer = new JLayer<JPanel>(this, layerUI);

        final Timer stopper = new Timer(4000,new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                layerUI.stop();
              }
            });
            stopper.setRepeats(false);
          if (!stopper.isRunning()) {
            stopper.start();
          }
        btnLoad.addActionListener(
          new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              layerUI.start();
              DataManager dataManager = new DataManager();
              try {
        dataManager.loadFromFile("C:/Users/*****PC/Downloads/****.csv");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
          }
        );
```

Comment: to ignore answer here, is wrong, Swing Timer is proper way, I'm sure that animation with Jlayer is there a few times, btw this is MadProgrammer's area

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm still think that this is your area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the file on another `Thread` and not the `Event Dispatch Thread`. Assuming your `loadFromFile` method blocks until it loads the file, you can then hide the layer, but you must hide on the `Event Dispatch Thread` and not the new `Thread` you started for loading the file.

Remove your timer and replace your try block with this:

```
    try {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                dataManager.loadFromFile("C:/Users/*****PC/Downloads/****.csv");
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        layerUI.stop();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```